# Angular -> Array

Tags: angular

I´m new to Angular and i have a simple Question.

I have an Array with Data that i become with an Input from an other Component.

On the HTML i can work with the Data.

But we can i work in ts. with the Data?

`@Input() settingData1: SettingsItem[];`

i would take 1 Number from the Array.

```html
this.test = this.settingData1[0];
```

but these don´t work.

when i take the answer from down i see it in the augury but not in the ts file
[image]

---

This is in the HTML Ablammtermine + {{ this.test.wert  }} Tage i get the value from wert  -> In the ts. File

> ngOnInit() {
>       this.getTage();
>
> }
>
> getTage() {
>       console.log(JSON.stringify(this._settingData1));
>       this.ds.getAblammTermin(this.test).subscribe(data => (this.ablammData = data));   }

i become in the Console undefined

Thx

Comment: You should show us this.settingData1 array so we can see how your data looks like.Just console.log( this.settingData1);

Comment: Try to show us the component.ts file. It might help the expert to guide you properly.

Comment: Where is the assignation done?

Comment: What is calling getTage()

Comment: If you want to use this.test[0], you need to call getTage() in the setter in my answer

Comment: It's working now. Why do I have to define it in the setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a setter to make sure your array is not undefined:

```
_settingData1: SettingsItem[];

@Input() set settingData1(data: SettingsItem[]) {
    this._settingData1 = data;
    this.test = data[0];
    this.getTage();
};
```

Angular update the html every life cycle so when the input is assigned, the html will be updated but that wont happen in your ts file unless you use a lifecycle hook(that is triggered after the assignation) or a setter like I gave you.

If you need to use the whole array, use the private variable_settingData1.

Comment: Hello. When i take your Answer i become an undefined. In the augury i see it

Comment: What becomes undefined (html displayed value?) and what does augury means (typo or the library?)

Comment: Then what is undefined?

Comment: When i try this in the ts File   console.log(this.test);

Comment: Where in the ts file

Comment: This is in the HTML Ablammtermine <span class="small">+ {{ this.test.wert  }} Tage</span> i get the value from wert  -> In the ts. File "  getTage() {
    console.log(this.test[0].wert);
    this.ds.getAblammTermin('' + this.test + '').subscribe(data => (this.ablammData = data));
  }
" i become in the Console undefined

Comment: If you are using this.test before it gets assigned you are going to get undefined. What is getTage(), where is it being used? And this.ds.getAblammTermin('' + this.test + '').subscribe(data => (this.ablammData = data)); }  is being called from where? getAblammTermin is receiving an object as a string as a parameter which doesnt make sens.

Comment: Post the whole ts file, because it feels like you are using something before it gets assigned but right now I cant tell you where.

Comment: onInit is being called before this.test is assigned, dont use this lifecycle hook since it will never work if you need to wait on an input value

Answer (score 0):

```html
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "Ãœbersicht";


  constructor(private ds: DataServiceService) { }

  _settingData1: SettingsItem[];

  ablammData: ablammTermin[];
  @Input() set settingData1(data: SettingsItem[]) {
    this._settingData1 = data;
    this.test = data[0];
  };

  test;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['SchafNr', 'AMA', 'Merkmal', 'Gebdat', 'Ablammtermin', 'Bemerkung'];


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTage();

  }

  getTage() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this._settingData1));
    this.ds.getAblammTermin(this.test).subscribe(data => (this.ablammData = data));
  }
```